# Error 'mysql.user' no es del tipo 'BASE TABLE'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estaba trabajando en proyecto con un crud, utilizando sessions y usuarios para hacer un login conectado a una base de datos, se me ha colado este error. He intentado resolverlo a través de reparar las tablas de la base de datos de 'mysql', en phpmyadmin, y no ha funcionado. Ya que al repararlas, la tabla user da este error. Me pueden decir como resolverlo?

Utilizo XAMPP como servicio. Inicializando Apache y Mysql. En mi programa me daba este error al inicializar un usuario

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'carlos'@'localhost' to database 'proyecto'

Al ver que es lo que pasaba en mi base de datos no ocurría nada, el problema estaba en las cuentas de usuarios del sistema:

> Error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" desde el manejador de la tabla Aria

No entenida nada, al buscar una solución podia ir a la tabla Usuario. En la base de datos mysql reparar las tablas. El problema venía cuando al reparar estas mismas, la tabla Usuario me sigue dando un error, este es

> Error "mysql.user" is not of type 'BASE TABLE' Status Operation failed

Desde aquí no se como solucionar este error.